# How to work together with cabal-3 and ghc (ghc-pkg, too)?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-new, ghc-pkg

With the release of cabal-3, the packages from Hackage are installed in a new location that the compiler `ghc` and `ghc-pkg` know nothing about.
In other words, packages are installed but not registered for `ghc`. `Ghci`, `ghc`, `ghc-pkg` cannot work.

For example,

```
cabal install safe --lib
```

Create file t1.hs

```
import Safe

t1 = tailMay [1,2,3]
```

Let's try:

```
> ghci t1.hs
GHCi, version 8.10.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/:? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main (t1.hs, interpreted)

t1.hs: 1: 1: error:
    Could not find module `Safe '
    Use -v (or `: set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Safe
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

This bug is described here

https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6262

and here

https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/17341

I use as a temporary solution setting a system variable

```
GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\cabal\store\ghc-8.10.2\package.db;
```

(Windwos 10, haskell-dev by chocolatey)

via
[On Windows, packages installed with cabal seem to be unavailable in ghc/ghci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497266/on-windows-packages-installed-with-cabal-seem-to-be-unavailable-in-ghc-ghci)

but with updates I will have to manually change this system variable.

Are there any more elegant solutions to this problem?

P.S. Unfortunately, this solution (via GHC's environment variable GHC_PACKAGE_PATH) is incompatible with Cabal :(

https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1944

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use the `--env` flag to make the libraries available to GHC whenever you are in the current directory:

```
~ $ mkdir /tmp/foo
~ $ cd /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo $ cabal install safe --lib --env .
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.8.3 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - safe-0.3.19 (lib) (requires build)
Configuring library for safe-0.3.19..
Preprocessing library for safe-0.3.19..
Building library for safe-0.3.19..
…
 > Installing library in /home/jojo/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/incoming/new-4056/home/jojo/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/safe-0.3.19-92fbaef88124b4508ce447f6245bc793f7a1748247ae68d10e449150df1069af/lib
t1.hs
/tmp/foo $ cat > t1.hs
import Safe

t1 = tailMay [1,2,3]
/tmp/foo $ ls -a
.  ..  .ghc.environment.x86_64-linux-8.8.3  t1.hs
/tmp/foo $ ghci t1.hs
GHCi, version 8.8.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /tmp/foo/.ghc.environment.x86_64-linux-8.8.3
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( t1.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main>
```

Note that you probably shouldn’t do this in a directory where you actually have a `foo.cabal` file. See [the documentation of `cabal v2-install`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-install) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Working with `GHC_ENVIRONMENT` is better:

```
  setx  GHC_ENVIRONMENT C:\Users\me\.ghc\x86_64-mingw32-8.10.2\environments\default
```

it helps for `ghc` and `ghci`.

After, in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\cabal\config` we should add

```
  package-db: C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\cabal\store\ghc-8.10.2\package.db
```

it helps for `cabal`.

Unfortunately, `ghc-pkg` still has problem and works with such flag:

```
  ghc-pkg list --user-package-db="C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\cabal\store\ghc-8.10.2\package.db"
```

For Linux the steps are similar.